# RegEx to extract value from html-input field

Tags: html, regex, input

We like to extract the value from the following input

```
<form action="xxxxxx" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="cFYtO3f_MtOi9dulLEnZFpwu33iqrQcmVyIZ9ntsNeDtvPPMEk_-G5AubkrxUi8iqYtJ3yBymB0csk4lLGGZppevAkcHZWuOjjG87bFIPbs1" />
<div class="container py-4">
        <h1>Consultation</h1>
```

So far we got the following regex:

```
(?<=input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value=")(.*?")
```

This gave us the result :

```
cFYtO3f_MtOi9dulLEnZFpwu33iqrQcmVyIZ9ntsNeDtvPPMEk_-G5AubkrxUi8iqYtJ3yBymB0csk4lLGGZppevAkcHZWuOjjG87bFIPbs1"
```

We only need to get rid of the trailing "

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Replace `(.*?")` with `[^"]*`.

Comment: `(.*?")` = > `(.*?)"` / `([^"]*)"`